# Keep UIInputViewController visible while hardware keyboard is connected

Tags: ios, keyboard, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

I have a custom keyboard extension that provides special symbols that can’t be typed with a hardware keyboard, similar to the emoji keyboard. iOS automatically dismisses third-party keyboards when a hardware keyboard is connected (but it doesn’t for the emoji keyboard), which is undesirable for my keyboard (and others such as GIF and sticker keyboards).

My question is how do you keep your custom keyboard visible when a hardware keyboard is connected?

SwiftKey was able to do this ([see here](https://support.swiftkey.com/hc/en-us/articles/202349752-Does-SwiftKey-Keyboard-for-iOS-work-with-external-Bluetooth-keyboards-)) but how?